# directive is not allowed here Nginx Passenger

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to enable Global Queuing in passenger and i'm using Nginx. When i set the flag **passenger_use_global_queue** I get an error **[emerg]: "passenger_use_global_queue" directive is not allowed here in nginx.conf:22"**. Does anyone know the propper place to put passenger_use_global_queue, or to get rid of the error message? Below is a snippit of my nginx.conf with the offending line:

```
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
      passenger_root /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-20090928/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5;
      passenger_ruby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-20090928/bin/ruby;
      passenger_use_global_queue on
```

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerUseGlobalQueue) says:

> This option may occur in the following
>   places:
>
> ```
> *      In a server configuration block.
> *      In a location configuration block.
> *      In an if configuration scope.
> ```